# Create dataframes AND named columns within a for loop using variables

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, assign

I'm trying to create a bunch of dataframes, & modify the variables within those dataframes, in a loop. The code below *almost* works, except that it creates a whole bunch of objects of the form `df_1$x_cs`, `df_1$yx_cs`  .....  What I want is 5 dataframes, with the $ elements enclosed, as usual.

```
nl<-seq(1,5)
for (i in nl) {
  assign(paste0("df_",nl[i]),data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=rnorm(10)))
}
ls()[grep("df_",ls())]
nls<-ls()[grep("df_",ls())]
for (df in nls) {
  print(df)
  for (var in names(get(df))) {
    print(var)
    assign(paste0(df,"$",paste0(var,"_cs")),cumsum(get(df)[[var]]))
  }
}
ls()[grep("df_",ls())]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know it's not the greatest idea to include `rm(list=ls())` in sample code - that others are going to copy and paste.

Comment: Hola Senor - sorry about that - but it's relevant to what shows up in the workspace, i.e. the 'grep' commands. I've been told it's good form to always rm() your workspace when working on something. It's also possibly a good idea to read code before you run it...  ;)

Comment: It is bad form to use similar names for creating a sequence of related objects.  Use a `list` instead.  This also avoids the problem of extra objects in your workspace.

Comment: Hi @MatthewLundberg - could you be more specific what you mean? I need similar names, to be able to systematically loop through them. Could you give and example of how it should be done? Thanks.

Comment: If the objects are in a list, looping through them is trivial.  Instead of assigning to `df_1` in the global environment, create a list `l` and assign to `l[['df_1']]`.

Comment: Hi @MatthewLundberg - I think I understand what you're saying, but it doesn't work as soon as I start trying to work on vars & subsets of `l[['df_1']][['x']]` . I think you're approach would work well - could you give a full example of the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found an even simpler and clearer way to do this, which I think will be my go-to in the future. This works very well:

```
for (i in seq(1,5)) {
  assign(paste0("df_",i),data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=rnorm(10)))
  rm(i)
}

nls<-ls()[grep("df_",ls())]
for (df in nls) {
  temp<-get(df)
  for (var in names(temp)) {
    temp[[paste0(var,"_cs")]]<-cumsum(temp[[var]])
  }
 assign(df, temp)
  rm(var,df,temp)
}
summary(get(nls[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to translate your code to use a `list` to do this, rather than names in the global environment:

```
lst <- list()
for (i in seq(1,5)) {
  lst[[i]] <- data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=rnorm(10))
}
lst <- lapply(lst, function(temp) {
  for (var in names(temp)) {
    temp[[paste0(var,"_cs")]]<-cumsum(temp[[var]])
  }
  return(temp)
})

summary(lst[[1]])
##        x               y                x_cs         y_cs       
##  Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :-2.7610   Min.   : 1   Min.   :-5.004  
##  1st Qu.: 3.25   1st Qu.:-1.4388   1st Qu.: 7   1st Qu.:-2.652  
##  Median : 5.50   Median :-0.7308   Median :18   Median :-1.656  
##  Mean   : 5.50   Mean   :-0.4338   Mean   :22   Mean   :-1.908  
##  3rd Qu.: 7.75   3rd Qu.: 0.7028   3rd Qu.:34   3rd Qu.:-1.207
```

Answer (score -1):

Much thanks to Blaser Nello on the R-Help list for solving this. I thought it best to share the answer.

> Here are two possible ways to do it:
>
> This would simplify your code a bit. But it changes the names of x_cs
>   to cs.x.

```
for (df in nls) {
  assign(df, cbind(get(df), cs=apply(get(df), 2, cumsum)))
  }
```

> This is closer to what you have done.

```
for (df in nls) {
  print(df)
  for (var in names(get(df))) {
    print(var)
    assign(df, within(get(df), assign(paste0(var,"_cs"),
cumsum(get(df)[[var]]))))
  }}
ls()[grep("df_",ls())]
```